# Error visual studio on a valid expression

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Why visual studio give me an error with :

```
public void afunction(int? bar){ somecode }

afunction(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["foo"])?null:int.Parse(Request["foo"]));
```

it give me there no implcit conversion between null and int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2nd and 3rd operands for the ? operator must have compatible types.  They don't in your case, the 2nd is null, the 3rd is int.  There is no *implicit* conversion from int to null nor from null to int.  Only explicit ones, like a cast to object or `Nullable<int>`.  You might consider using this:

```
afunction(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["foo"]) ? default(int?) : int.Parse(Request["foo"]));
```

No problem here since there *is* an implicit conversion from int to int?

Comment: I understand what you say, but it seems to be a weakness in the language

Comment: Standard fare in a statically typed language, like C#, that allows an expression to be a statement.  Which prevents the compiler from inferring the intended conversion from the result type.  That it is possible to do so in a lot of cases, like yours, didn't sway the language designers.  Consistency was important to them.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change your approach slightly, such as:

```
? null : new Nullable<int>(int.Parse(Request["foo"]));
```

The compiler is expressing that you are responsible for the conversion of types.

Comment: Resharper suggest me " ? null : new int?(int.Parse(Request["idM"])) "

Answer (score 1):

The simplified version:

```
  int? x = true ? null : 1;
```

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between `<null>` and 'int'

So the conditional operator does not work as you expect (with regards to type conversions).
A refactoring won't hurt anyway, just split it up to something readable.

Comment: it was not a problem of refactoring but of understanding, thanks